# Graph theory: paths in a tree in python

Tags: python, graph-theory

the adjacency list (for example): adj = [ [1,2],[2,3],[ ],[4],[ ] ] the assumption is that the graph is always a directed tree

I need to make a path recursion and store each path in a variable called full_path

**pseudo-code:**

for i in range(0, len(adj), 1):

- use each path possible until you reach a dead end
- the variable path contains the nodes you've just visited and re-initialise every time we reach a dead end, before re-initialising we save it as a nested list in full_path

**for our example that would give:**

- 0->1->2->[ ]      so path = [0,1,2]
- 0->1->3->4->[ ]   so path = [0,1,3,4]
- 0->2->[ ]         so path = [0,2]
- 1->2->[ ]         so path = [1,2]
- 1->3->4->[ ]      so path = [1,3,4]
- 2->[ ]            so path = [2]
- 3->4->[ ]         so path = [3,4]
- 4->[ ]            so path = [4]

And therefore full_path = [ [0,1,2], [0,1,3,4], [0,2], [1,2], [1,3,4], [2], [3,4], [4] ]. This is the output the function must give to match the teacher's expectations.
('[ ]' means it has reached a dead end)

```
for i in range(0,len(adj),1):
    for j in range(0,len(adj[i]),1):
        path += [i]
        current_node= j# , True
        a = len(adj[current_node])
        while a >0:      # to stop when a node leads to nowhere:  adj[j] = [] and so len(adj[j])==0
            for k in range(0,len(adj[current_node]),1):
                current_node = adj[current_node][k]
                path += [current_node]
                a = len(adj[current_node])
            final_path += [list(dict.fromkeys(path))]
            path = []
```

Above is what I did so far but it does not works at all

Comment: "a = len(adj[current_node])"  Looks to me like you do not reduce the length adj[cureent_node] so this will always return same value - endless loop.

Comment: I thought the line 10 was doing that

Comment: What is line 10?  You have not posted any line numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking#:%7E:text=Backtracking%20is%20a%20general%20algorithm,completed%20to%20a%20valid%20solution.) in this problem because of the recursive nature of the problem using directed trees.

```py
adj = [ [1,2],[2,3],[ ],[4],[ ] ]

def getAllPath(adj):
  pathes = [] # list of all pathes reached <- what you want
  path = [] # to hold the current path
  def dfs(node):
    if not adj[node]: # if current node has no children
      pathes.append(path.copy()) # append a copy of current path to pathes
    else:
      for next_node in adj[node]:
        if next_node not in path: # if current node is not visited (useless if it's a directed tree)
          path.append(next_node) # push the next_node to the current path
          dfs(next_node)         # build the rest of the path
          path.pop()             # remove it from the path.
        
  for node in range(len(adj)): # loop over all nodes in the graph
    path.append(node) # add current start node to the path
    dfs(node)         # build the rest of the path
    path.pop()        # remove the start node
  return pathes
```

output

```
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 3, 4], [0, 2], [1, 2], [1, 3, 4], [2], [3, 4], [4]]
```